# Spring bean null on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to auto wire a bean and it is always null when i try to do it. No matter how i attempt (auto or constructor / property injection) it is always null.

What am I doing incorrectly please?

```
package com.ricki.relocate.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ricki.relocate.database.RelocateServiceDaoImpl;

@Path("/service")
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private RelocateServiceDaoImpl service; 

    @Path("/createUser")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String createUser(@QueryParam("firstname") String firstname, @QueryParam("lastname") String lastname, @QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password) {
        boolean result = service.createNewUser(firstname, lastname, username, password);
        return Boolean.toString(result);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

    <!-- Initialization for data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Relocate" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for RelocateServiceDaoImpl bean -->
    <bean id="relocateServiceDaoImpl" class="com.ricki.relocate.database.RelocateServiceDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for service bean which uses dao bean -->
    <bean id="service" class="com.ricki.relocate.service.Service">
        <property name="relocateServiceDao" ref="relocateServiceDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

</beans>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/relocate/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Spring doesn't automagically inject fields/methods/constructors of Jersey (or whatever jaxrs implementation this is) managed objects. Have you set up the appropriate integration of the two?

Comment: no i haven't - i was following a tutorial of which i have now deviated

Comment: That's likely where the problem is. Look for Spring-Jersey bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that Spring knows nothing about your com.ricki.relocate.service.Service class - it is simply doesn't exist in Spring context.

You should annotate it with `@Component` annotation so Spring will be able to discover it and perform autowirings, and you should also change Jersey Servlet class to `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet`. This should work.

Try looking at this tutorial: 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/